# Django - How can I make an if statement using step_number and another Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to use the step_number function (this function is being used to go to the next page) and at the same time validate the fields if they are blank using Javascript. I would like to know what can be done in order to get both working without using a form. Is there a way to include the step_number in the Javascript function?

So far I got this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="mt-3">
    <button class="button btn-navigate-form-step" type="button" step_number="2" onclick="validatefields1()">Next</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function validatefields1() {
  let x = document.forms["checklistForm"]["user_name"].value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("Name must be filled out");
    return false;
  }
}
```

**Javascript `step_number`**

```
/**
 * Define a function to navigate betweens form steps.
 * It accepts one parameter. That is - step number.
 */
 const navigateToFormStep = (stepNumber) => {
    /**
     * Hide all form steps.
     */
    document.querySelectorAll(".form-step").forEach((formStepElement) => {
        formStepElement.classList.add("d-none");
    });
    /**
     * Mark all form steps as unfinished.
     */
    document.querySelectorAll(".form-stepper-list").forEach((formStepHeader) => {
        formStepHeader.classList.add("form-stepper-unfinished");
        formStepHeader.classList.remove("form-stepper-active", "form-stepper-completed");
    });
    /**
     * Show the current form step (as passed to the function).
     */
    document.querySelector("#step-" + stepNumber).classList.remove("d-none");
    /**
     * Select the form step circle (progress bar).
     */
    const formStepCircle = document.querySelector('li[step="' + stepNumber + '"]');
    /**
     * Mark the current form step as active.
     */
    formStepCircle.classList.remove("form-stepper-unfinished", "form-stepper-completed");
    formStepCircle.classList.add("form-stepper-active");
    /**
     * Loop through each form step circles.
     * This loop will continue up to the current step number.
     * Example: If the current step is 3,
     * then the loop will perform operations for step 1 and 2.
     */
    for (let index = 0; index < stepNumber; index++) {
        /**
         * Select the form step circle (progress bar).
         */
        const formStepCircle = document.querySelector('li[step="' + index + '"]');
        /**
         * Check if the element exist. If yes, then proceed.
         */
        if (formStepCircle) {
            /**
             * Mark the form step as completed.
             */
            formStepCircle.classList.remove("form-stepper-unfinished", "form-stepper-active");
            formStepCircle.classList.add("form-stepper-completed");
        }
    }
};
/**
 * Select all form navigation buttons, and loop through them.
 */
document.querySelectorAll(".btn-navigate-form-step").forEach((formNavigationBtn) => {
    /**
     * Add a click event listener to the button.
     */
    formNavigationBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        /**
         * Get the value of the step.
         */
        const stepNumber = parseInt(formNavigationBtn.getAttribute("step_number"));
        /**
         * Call the function to navigate to the target form step.
         */
        navigateToFormStep(stepNumber);
    });
});
```

Comment: How the `step_number` is initially populated? From Django template variable?

Comment: @EgorWexler, hello! I added the ```step_number``` code.

Comment: the provided code does not contain logic for populating `step_number` - it only binds click listeners to it. Question is how in your example number `2` is populated

Comment: How can I find that?